# Adding PopoverviewController to UIBarButtonItem Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uipopover

Added popoverViewController to bar button

```
public partial class MagicViewController : UIViewController
    {

        UIBarButtonItem btn_Setting;
//      UIPopoverController popoverController;
        SettingPopoverViewController settingController;
        public DashBoardViewController(){

            btn_Setting = new UIBarButtonItem (
                "Setting", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, 
                (s, e) => {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Setting!!!");
                    settingController = new SettingPopoverViewController();
                var popoverController = new UIPopoverController(settingController);
                    popoverController.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(320,320);
                    popoverController.PresentFromRect (new RectangleF (0,0,320,320),View,UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up,true);

                });
            NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = btn_Setting;
        }
```

how to load popoverview controller on barButtonItem iOS

Comment: Its crashes  NSInvalidArgumentException: -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.  When running application in iPad its works fine when run in iPhone its crashes.... UIPopovercontroller will not applicable  for iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use UIPopoverController on iPhone.

From [Apple Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices.
>   Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.